# Insert symbols MySQL

Tags: mysql

Now I would like to insert symbols to my MySQL table 
I've spent a few hours over the net searching for an answer but I might be stupid or not because I could not find what I wanted

Now I insert my data to the database using command line 
How can I insert symbols like "@;#,%,$,&,',..." into the table 
Table collation is set to UTF8_unicode_CI

command I use

```
INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ( "Assassin's Creed® 3" )
```

Now it shows up as

AssassinтАЩs Creed┬о 3

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What exactly is not working? The symbols you show should not be a problem at all. Umlauts like `ÄÖÜ` might but we need more info about what you are doing

Comment: With the exception of the single quote, they should all just be inserted as literals. Please post an example of what you're doing and how it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

your query is right only the way you show it u must use  `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`

> This first function is identical to
>   htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except
>   with htmlentities(), all characters
>   which have HTML character entity
>   equivalents are translated into these
>   entities.

ex:    `echo  htmlspecialchars($row['name']) ;`

- be sure to pass values to `mysql` by  `mysql_real_escape_string()` to avoid any SQL Injection problems.